# Jump to Element, Window Centered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a simple function that when you leave a reply, it jumps to you to a reply box and highlights it. It works great, except the box tends to hug the top of the window. **I was wondering what a good trick might be to get it to land centered vertical.**

Here is my code thus far:

```
function jump_to(id){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(id).offset().top }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Offset the vertical position by half of the users display height.

Answer (score 0):

```
function jump_to(id){
    var viewportHalfHt = $(window).height() / 2;

    $("html, body").animate({ 
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top + viewportHalfHt 
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: For some reason this is landing me way below the destination. But that may be my error. I'll check it out. Your solution is probably right.